# MySQL updating part of the record after X many characters

Tags: mysql, updates

Let's say that I have a record like `https://stackoverflow.com//questions/`, somehow this happened and I want to update the record as `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/`.

So far I thought of replacing every occurrence of `//` but this would break `https://` part as `http:/` too.

I have identified all the broken records via:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '//', -1) FROM url) FROM table_name WHERE length(TRIM(TRAILING SUBSTRING_INDEX(url, '//', -1) FROM url)) > 8;
```

This checks after 8 characters, so that all `http://` and `https://` occurrences are skipped. There're currently 302 URLs in this situation.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: This is one case where you should use regex over normal string matching functions..

Comment: I guess that's about it: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-regular-expression-regexp.aspx I'll try, thank you for the suggestion. I forgot existence of regex within MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace twice.

So the problem is that also `https://` becomes `https:/` ?
Just means you need to add that 1 lost slash again.

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET url = REPLACE(REPLACE(url,'//','/'),':/','://')
WHERE url LIKE '%://%//%'
```

Comment: This was a very simple solution, and it works just fine. Thank you!

Comment: Thx. Of course there's a tiny assumption with this.  That the `:/`  isn't used in the url after the protocol.  But at least I have never seen such url. So it's an acceptable risk.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
SET @val = 'https://stackoverflow.com//questions/';

select 
  concat(
    substr(@val, 1, instr(@val, '//') + 1), 
    replace(substr(@val, instr(@val, '//') + 2),'//', '/')
)
```

it replaces all occurrences of `//` after the 1st with `/`
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/64aZyDjGgXafwN3N6ww93y/0)
So you can use it in an update:

```
update tablename
set mycolumn = concat(
        substr(mycolumn, 1, instr(mycolumn, '//') + 1), 
        replace(substr(mycolumn, instr(mycolumn, '//') + 2),'//', '/')
)
```

Comment: I'm getting a `ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4`. What could be the error, I couldn't spot it?

Comment: One more parenthesis at the end of the update statement I think. I edited.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and help!